# Subnet IPv4 CIDR Block

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip-address, amazon-vpc, subnet, cidr

I have a legacy VPC that was created with an IPv4 CIDR of `10.1.0.0/24`, there is one public subnet that shares the same range `10.1.0.0/24`

I am trying to create a new private subnet in the VPC so that I can have a lambda access private resources as well as make requests to the internet but I am struggling to find a valid IPv$ CIDR block for the new subnet.

What is a range that would fit within these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your one subnet is **using the entire IP range** allocated to that VPC. Typically, a larger range would be assigned to a VPC (eg `/16`).

Fortunately, you can **Edit CIDRs** and **Add new IPv4 CIDR** to the VPC, such as `10.1.1.0/24`. You can then add a subnet with that additional IP range.